# Can Flink be used with Kotlin?

Tags: scala, kotlin, apache-flink, flink-streaming, bigdata

I have a project where I need to stream data in real time. I've written the instream data to a kafka topic. Now I need to read this data and process it. For this, I plan to use Flink.
My dilemma is that I do not know either Java, Scala or Kotlin. I would have to learn one of them to use Flink and since Kotlin is the latest of the lot, I thought I should learn that, but is it actually compatible with Flink?
I am completely new to any sort of data streaming so please pardon any mistakes in my question and definitely correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If Flink is written in Java (or Scala or Kotlin) you can use any of these three languages because they run on the JVM (using the Java bytecode).

Comment: Flink is written in both Java and Scala but not Kotlin. I understand that they all use the same JVM to compile.

Comment: If something is using JVM that means that all JVM languages are compatible with it (i.e. you can use any language if the code written with a JVM language)

Comment: The only issue currently is that lambdas don't work with Kotlin due to a Kotlin compiler issue. Bug tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-23979

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is that you can use any JVM language to interact with Flink: java, kotlin, scala (and probably even something like groovy).

That said, you would probably have some issues finding answers to questions. Flink officially supports scala and java so I would start with either of those two.

Lastly, kotlin being the latest has nothing to do with how good it is. People are using all three successfully. This is mostly a matter of preference (unless you have some special use case).

Comment: That blog post isn't talking about removing Scala support in Flink, it removes a hard dependency on Scala for those that don't want to use it.